# gcloud error: ApiError: Not Found at new util.ApiError

Tags: node.js, upload, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node, buckets

Anyone familiar with this gcloud exception:

> ApiError: Not Found at new util.ApiError
>   (/site/node_modules/gcloud/lib/common/util.js:128:10) at
>   Object.parseHttpRespBody
>   (/site/node_modules/gcloud/lib/common/util.js:206:30) at
>   Object.handleResp
>   (/site/node_modules/gcloud/lib/common/util.js:146:18) at
>   /site/node_modules/gcloud/lib/common/util.js:447:12 at
>   Request.onResponse [as _callback]
>   (/site/node_modules/gcloud/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:120:7)
>   at Request.self.callback
>   (/site/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22) at Request.emit
>   (events.js:98:17) at Request.
>   (/site/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10) at Request.emit
>   (events.js:95:17) at IncomingMessage.
>   (/site/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12) at IncomingMessage.emit
>   (events.js:117:20) at _stream_readable.js:944:16 at
>   process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:492:13)

It appears only in production (of course) and currently consistently. It used to appear periodically and the assumption was that it is a glitch @ gCloud since locally it could not be reproduced. It is related to the part of the code which uses the simplest gCloud lib method `bucket.upload` with no parameters other than the file ... Here is the current function which does it:

```
function uploadToGoogleCloud(filePath, makePublic) {
  var gstorage = gcloud.storage({
    projectId: EXAMPLE_projectId,
    credentials: EXAMPLE_credentials,
  });

  var spBucket = Promise.promisifyAll(gstorage.bucket(EXAMPLE_bucket));

  return spBucket.uploadAsync(filePath).then(function(file) {
    if (makePublic) {
      var fileAsync = Promise.promisifyAll(file);
      return fileAsync.makePublicAsync().then(function() {
        return file;
      });
    }
    return file;
  });
}
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it appears that the files are actually being uploaded but not made public. Hoping that would help with some suggestions. We are still trying to resolve this.

Comment: The GCS API error reporting is a joke.  They provide no details as to what's going wrong.  Drives me nuts.

Comment: @Akrion were you able to solve this issue? Does any of the other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044835/firebase-cloud-function-api-error-with-google-cloud-storage/43106877#43106877) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853519/google-cloud-storage-error-during-upload-gcs-resumable-upload-json-renaming-o) work for you? If so providing your solution here will better help the community.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a bit obscure, but was correct for me. I got this error when I in some cases were trying to write to a bigquery table that did not exist (I accidentally passed "undefined" as the tablename), I suspect that there is some 404 error coercion going on under the hood.