# Firebase: ApiError: Unauthorized Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have firebase cloud function working, but today I am seeing following error:

Please suggest what is wrong with firebase functions.

```
ApiError: Unauthorized
        at new util.ApiError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:107:10)
        at Object.parseHttpRespMessage (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:149:33)
        at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:124:18)
        at Duplexify.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/file.js:711:21)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Duplexify.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Note: I know they were migrating to newer nodejs, Is it because of it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution here solved the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106877/1590595

I am keeping an eye, if it occurs, I will update the answer.